# jQuery preloading images function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, forgive my ignorance about this subject but there's just so many ways to do this that I'm trying to find just one way to do it.

How come this fiddle works?  I thought it was supposed to alert when it detects all the images have been loaded but I didn't place any images in the HTML part.

fid: https://jsfiddle.net/mbxyoxnx/1/

```js
function preload(files, cb) {
    var len = files.length;
    $(files.map(function(f) {
        return '<img src="'+f+'" />';
    }).join('')).load(function () {
        if(--len===0) {
            cb();
        }
    });
}

preload(["http://mydailymix.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/i_love_video_games_by_cocodie-d5aokgg.jpg", "http://img07.deviantart.net/0528/i/2012/198/3/4/yo_videogames__by_ry_spirit-d57k3ay.jpg", "http://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Nintendo-Video-Game-Characters.jpg","http://site-macgasm.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/space-invaders.jpg"], function() {
alert('nice');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<img src="http://mydailymix.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/i_love_video_games_by_cocodie-d5aokgg.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://img07.deviantart.net/0528/i/2012/198/3/4/yo_videogames__by_ry_spirit-d57k3ay.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://screenrant.com/wp-content/uploads/Nintendo-Video-Game-Characters.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://site-macgasm.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/space-invaders.jpg" alt="">

-->
```

Comment: You've told it to preload a file in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To make it detect your images and fire after all loaded, you need to do something like:
https://jsfiddle.net/mbxyoxnx/3/

```
var files = $("img").map( function() {
   return $(this).attr("src");
});

preload( files.toArray(), function() {
   alert( "all images loaded" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I know that it's working?  I plugged it into my js file but I don't see a visible difference load wise.

Comment: Try to throttle your connection with Chrome Dev Tools... 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/network-conditions?hl=en#emulate-network-connectivity